# Creating another webpart zone within a document library

Tags: web-part, document-library, navigation

I am fairly new to SharePoint and I have been asked to improve our company's SharePoint site. Currently I have quite a few document libraries and each document library has several views. I am looking for a way to spruce up the navigation bar on our site. Through my research I have been able to modify some code so that using a script editor web part I can have a very good looking navigation bar on the left side of the page. My problem is that in the document library I only have one web part zone called main and within that zone I can only add web parts on the top or bottom of the documents. I need to be able to either create another web part zone to the left or within the main web part zone force the web parts to the side of the documents. I also don't have access to the master page. I have tried adding a table to the main web part but that takes away the functionality of the multiple views of the document library. I have also tried to change the html/css code so that the navigation bar goes horizontally across the top but it defaults back to vertical. Thank you in advance for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's generally bad practice (although I admit I can provide no citation here), to add web parts to your document library **page**. Rather, you should create a site **page**, add a document library web part to it, and then customise this page as you see fit.

Essentially what you're doing currently, is heavily customising a view, and you risk corrupting the list and navigation.

Comment: When I create a site page and try to add a web part I do not see a web part called document library. It will allow me to add an app which is basically a view into another document library page, but no web part that is a document library.

Comment: Correct, you add a view of that document library onto a page. Functionally, this is the same thing, you can edit that web part to change the default view/change the tool bar type etc. Anything you do through this "view", will affect a change in the document library. They are one and the same thing, you now just have an extra access point

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I have document libraries with multiple views that the user needs to be able to access. In a web part app when you click on another view within the document library instead of showing you that view it links you directly to the document library and that is not what I want to have happen.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a limitation of SharePoint's design. I would recommend asking for access to the master page. If your administrators are hesitant to give this to you, then arguably this isn't something they would wish you to be doing.